# How to pass admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to the update() method, using CloudFunction coded in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to pass admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to the update() method? 
I want to insert this in an array, like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNote = functions.https.onCall(async(data,context)=>{
const numeroSender: string = data['numeroSender'];
const amisA = admin.firestore().collection('Amis').doc(numeroReceiver);
const connaissanceABBA:number = 3.0;
const version:number = 1;
const time = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
await amisA.update({
            [`amis.${numeroSender}`] : [time,connaissanceABBA,version]
        });
});
```

but I get this error

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an 
alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an 
optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid 
Firestore value. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() cannot be used inside of 
an array (found in field `amis.+33651177261`.`0`).
at WriteBatch.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write- 
batch.js:367:23)
at DocumentReference.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
admin/node_modules/@google- 
cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:372:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/lib/index.js:121:25)
at next (native)
at fulfilled (/user_code/lib/index.js:4:58)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp() cannot be used inside of 
an array` there you have your answer, maybe a map would fit u better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As detailed in the error message you receive, "`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` cannot be used inside of an array".

Which is what you do with:

```
const time = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
await amisA.update({
            [`amis.${numeroSender}`] : [time,connaissanceABBA,version]
        });
});
```

You might have to change your data model and, for example, replace your array by a map, as follows:

```
const time = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
await amisA.update({
            [`amis.${numeroSender}`] : 
               {
        connaissanceABBA: connaissanceABBA,
        version: version,
        ts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), you can use admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()

```
const time = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
await amisA.update({
        [`amis.${numeroSender}`] : 
           {
    connaissanceABBA: connaissanceABBA,
    version: version,
    ts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Please explain the difference between `now` and `serverTimestamp`. I love-hate the Firebase docs, but I suspect the difference is that serverTimestamp is taken from the server while `now` is not and is available without waiting for server processing. Correct?

Comment: @Drew What is the problem with `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

Comment: @SimonB. just found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60243513/12695188