# What is the difference between admin.firestore.Timestamp.now() and admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#servertimestamp

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#now

I am not sure I understand the difference. Could someone explain this ?

That is: what difference would I obtain if I just used firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now() as a timestamp property of the object I am about to write instead of firebase.firestore.FieldValue.servertimestamp() ?

I would imagine there are some precision gains ? How much ? Or is it something else ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Timestamp.now()` generates the timestamp using the client machine's clock, which could be wrong, even drastically wrong.

`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` encodes a token into the document field that gets translated into a timestamp using the clock on Google's servers whenever the write operation is received (not at the time it was issued from the client).  The clock time on all Google services are [meticulously](https://developers.google.com/time/smear) guaranteed to be correct, no matter what a malicious user does.

If you absolutely need a correct time, especially one that needs to get checked by [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) using [request.time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time), you should use the server timestamp.  If you need the client's clock time, use `Timestamp.now()`.  It's almost always the case that a server timestamp is preferred.

Comment: What if I use admin.firestore.Timestamp.now() (using the Node.js SDK) and make sure to keep all my servers in one location ? Any difference then ?

Comment: No, it's still exactly as I described. Server timestamps use Google server sense of time, and can be checked in security rules from mobile and web clients.  Anything else can not.

Comment: @DougStevenson Running using firebase functions (on same area as the firebase project) will result the **same** timestamp. Is that right?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've encountered a problem with using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` when combined with `FieldValue.arrayUnion()`. I'm unsure if this should be a feature request or a bug report, but basically I can add an object using `Timestamp.now()` as a field into an existing array using arrayUnion() but it throws an error using serverTimestamp(). Do you know the proper channel I should voice this concern in?