# Firestore append to array (field type) an object with server timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to insert an object to the Firestore document as per the code mentioned below. but it's throwing the error

```
   .update({
           "comments": firebase.fieldValue.arrayUnion({
            userId,
            comment: data.comment,
            createdAt: firebase.fieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
     })
```

**Error**:

> FirebaseError: Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with update() and set() (found in document...)

How can I add a timestamp to the pushed array object or is there any other way to achieve a similar result? what am I getting from the error above is I can't use the timestamp inside `arrayUnion`

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` as the value to an arrayUnion since that function does not return a `timestamp` but a sentinel to be used in a `set()` or `update()`. In order to do that you need to get the actual [`timestamp` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor) value. And the way to get this value differs from the local to the admin SDK, so depending on what you are using you could do something like this:

**For the Admin SDK**:

```
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

const created_at = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

**For the Local SDK**:

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const created_at = Timestamp.now()
```

And then you can update your document by doing this:

```
.update({
       "comments": firebase.fieldValue.arrayUnion({
        userId,
        comment: data.comment,
        createdAt: created_at,
 })
```

Comment: It's not working, I think this serverTimestamp can only be called from inside of set or update methods

Comment: Yeah, I am updating the answer, give me a sec.

Comment: Edited, try it out. :)

Comment: **Important note:** `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` encodes a token into the document field that gets translated into a timestamp using the clock on Google's servers whenever the write operation is received. But `Timestamp.now()` generates the timestamp using the client machine's clock, which could be wrong, even drastically wrong. [Read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60243513/1526396). So I would love to hear another way of using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` with `arrayUnion`. If anyone knows please share.