# Adding a Timestamp to a nested object in Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set a timestamp field on a nested element to the current time:

```
docRef.update({
   arrayOfStuff: {
        id: 123,
        dateAdded: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
   }
})
```

I get the error:

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp() cannot be used inside of an array
```

Using `Date.now()` gets me an int value, not a timestamp.

Trying `Firestore.Timestamp.fromDate()` yields the error:

```
TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
    at Function.fromDate (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/timestamp.js:108:42)
    at firestoreDB.doc.get.then.site (/srv/index.js:32:45)
```

where line 32 of index.js is:

```
let now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(Date.now());
```

Thoughts?

Comment: So I have decided to move forward using:


```let now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()```

It yields a "timestamp" value in Firestore.  I suspect the difference is that the timestamp I get comes from when the code runs, as opposed to serverTimestamp() that I believe is the time that the data is actually stored in Firestore (there can be a delay between the two times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1849#issuecomment-500031383), "`FieldValue.serverTimestamp` can't be supported inside arrays without a major overhaul of the way Firestore works". So this behavior is expected.

Searching a bit more, I was able to find a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526455/11928130) by Renaud Tarnec. Although he mentioned that you might need to change your data model.

I hope this helps.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220365/firebase-firestore-timestamp-not-allowed-inside-array/67221212#67221212) a possible workaround with a Cloud Function and a field in the doc (not in an array) that contains the timestamp.