# Can't update firestore document array field with timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update document but when I try to put `serverTimestamp()`, document just doesn't updates:

```
    await updateDoc(ref, {
        'process.votings': arrayUnion({
            finished: false,
            timer: {
                time: 60,
                finishedAt: null,
                startedAt: serverTimestamp()
            },
            votes: [],
            winner: null,
            candidates: candidates.map(candidate => candidate.id),
            question: null
        })
    })
```

When I don't put `serverTimestamp()` everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverTimestamp()` does not work inside an array, so what you're trying to do isn't currently possible.

See also:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1849#issuecomment-500031383
- [Adding a Timestamp to a nested object in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018510/adding-a-timestamp-to-a-nested-object-in-cloud-firestore)
- [How to pass admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to the update() method, using CloudFunction coded in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526348/how-to-pass-admin-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-the-update-method/56526455#56526455)

You might want to consider an altnerative way to model your data, possibly by using separate documents in a nested subcollection rather than an array field in a single document.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that post you mentioned